# How to interpret AddressSanitizer output?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

Seems AddressSanitizer detected `heap-buffer-overflow` but output not so clear as for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer#Heap-buffer-overflow).

How can I get line at which overflow occurred?

How can I interpret this results?

```
[1m[31m==27467== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60a4000b2a80 at pc 0x40730e bp 0x7fffffffcf10 sp 0x7fffffffcf08
[1m[0m[1m[34mWRITE of size 8 at 0x60a4000b2a80 thread T0[1m[0m
    #0 0x40730d (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x40730d)
    #1 0x406624 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x406624)
    #2 0x40211b (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x40211b)
    #3 0x402bf3 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x402bf3)
    #4 0x7ffff3866f44 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21f44)
    #5 0x401d78 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x401d78)
[1m[32m0x60a4000b2a80 is located 0 bytes to the right of 74368-byte region [0x60a4000a0800,0x60a4000b2a80)
[1m[0m[1m[35mallocated by thread T0 here:[1m[0m
    #0 0x7ffff413941a (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x1541a)
    #1 0x7ffff7b3bfb7 (/home/user/libs/opencv-2.4.13_QT/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.13+0x203fb7)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c150000e500: [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e510: [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e520: [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e530: [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e540: [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m [1m[0m00[1m[0m
=>0x0c150000e550:[[1m[31mfa[1m[0m][1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e560: [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e570: [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e580: [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e590: [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  0x0c150000e5a0: [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           [1m[0m00[1m[0m
  Partially addressable: [1m[0m01[1m[0m [1m[0m02[1m[0m [1m[0m03[1m[0m [1m[0m04[1m[0m [1m[0m05[1m[0m [1m[0m06[1m[0m [1m[0m07[1m[0m 
  Heap left redzone:     [1m[31mfa[1m[0m
  Heap righ redzone:     [1m[31mfb[1m[0m
  Freed Heap region:     [1m[35mfd[1m[0m
  Stack left redzone:    [1m[31mf1[1m[0m
  Stack mid redzone:     [1m[31mf2[1m[0m
  Stack right redzone:   [1m[31mf3[1m[0m
  Stack partial redzone: [1m[31mf4[1m[0m
  Stack after return:    [1m[35mf5[1m[0m
  Stack use after scope: [1m[35mf8[1m[0m
  Global redzone:        [1m[31mf9[1m[0m
  Global init order:     [1m[36mf6[1m[0m
  Poisoned by user:      [1m[34mf7[1m[0m
  ASan internal:         [1m[33mfe[1m[0m
==27467== ABORTING
```

Comment: Looks like your code (or somebody's code running in your program) wrote 8 bytes, past the end of a dynamically allocated memory buffer.

Comment: You might get something more readable if you compile your binary with debug symbols turned on (`-g`)

Comment: @Smeeheey I already built it with `-O0 -g`

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to set some environment variables before executing your program in order to get readable output: namely `ASAN_OPTIONS`, `symbolize` and `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` (which assumes you have a suitable symbolizer). So something like this:

```
ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1 ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=$(shell which llvm-symbolizer) ./a.out
```

This is from the documentation [here](https://gist.github.com/kwk/4171e37f4bcdf7705329)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you also copied the ANSI color codes into your output.
Here's a clearer version:

```
==27467== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60a4000b2a80 at pc 0x40730e bp 0x7fffffffcf10 sp 0x7fffffffcf08
WRITE of size 8 at 0x60a4000b2a80 thread T0
    #0 0x40730d (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x40730d)
    #1 0x406624 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x406624)
    #2 0x40211b (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x40211b)
    #3 0x402bf3 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x402bf3)
    #4 0x7ffff3866f44 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21f44)
    #5 0x401d78 (/home/user/Desktop/ImageRegistration/ImageRegistration+0x401d78)
0x60a4000b2a80 is located 0 bytes to the right of 74368-byte region [0x60a4000a0800,0x60a4000b2a80)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7ffff413941a (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.0.0.0+0x1541a)
    #1 0x7ffff7b3bfb7 (/home/user/libs/opencv-2.4.13_QT/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.13+0x203fb7)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c150000e500: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c150000e510: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c150000e520: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c150000e530: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c150000e540: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c150000e550:[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c150000e560: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c150000e570: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c150000e580: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c150000e590: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c150000e5a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap righ redzone:     fb
  Freed Heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==27467== ABORTING
```

To get line numbers, you must specify the path to the llvm-symbolizer binary, either by having it accessible through the `PATH` environment variable, or by specifying its pathname directly in the `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: OP is using GCC, symbolizer is not needed there (GCC uses libbacktrace library instead).